Weird behaviors with transform.LookRotation when looking at position+Vector3
I'm working on a character controller for an isometric retro shooter. However, when making the character rotate towards where they are moving, I encountered some issues.

The character doesn't fully rotate; instead of 90 degrees, it's about 85.
The character's rotation sometimes lags and glitches when changing directions.

Here is my code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MoveSpeed;
    private CharacterController controller;
    public Quaternion lookTo;

    private Vector3 move;
    public Vector3 velocity; //For Debugging
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Vertical")*MoveSpeed*-1f;
        float moveY = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")*MoveSpeed;
        move = new Vector3(moveX, 0f, moveY);
        velocity = controller.velocity;
        lookTo = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position+controller.velocity);
        lookTo.z = 0f;
        lookTo.x = 0f;
        transform.rotation = lookTo;
       
        controller.Move(move);
    }
}

Does anyone know what I did wrong?
Thank you!

Three mistakes:

You're reading the controller's velocity before you've fed it the latest input, so this is stale data, adding a frame of latency to your rotation. That accounts for the lag you're seeing.

The input to LookRotation() needs to be the direction to look in, not a position to look at.
Do not add the object's position here:
lookTo = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position+controller.velocity);

That accounts for the less-than-90° rotation you observe, since the position offset was adding an unwanted bias.

The output is a quaternion, not a set of Euler angles. You should not manipulate the x y z w components of a quaternion individually unless you know what you're doing with imaginary numbers in 4-dimensional space.


Corrected code would look like this:
void Update()
{
    float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Vertical")*MoveSpeed*-1f;
    float moveY = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")*MoveSpeed;
    move = new Vector3(moveX, 0f, moveY);
        
    // Since move.y is 0 by construction,
    // this will be a pure yaw (y) rotation.
    // No need to mess with its components.
    lookTo = Quaternion.LookRotation(move);

    transform.rotation = lookTo;
       
    controller.Move(move);
}

